# check if image exists with <image src="@routes.Assets.at("public/images", "logo.png")">

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

In playframework to load images i am using @routes.Assets.at

like

But i want to load this image only if this logo.png is available. 
Because in case where there is no image it is showing empty image space.

Is there any syntax like

@routes.Assets.at("public/images", "logo.png").getorelse() kind of .. but the return type is not of type option here.

Comment: So you won't know if the image will be there after compile time? Cause if this is the case you need to look into how Play manages asset files in Production vs Development mode. In Prod mode, any files added to asset after the server is launched in Prod mode will not be recognizable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt your approach is the correct one since images need width, height and an alt attribute.  If you have that data you should already know that the image exists.

You can create a template img.scala.html:

```
@(path: String, width: Int, height: Int, alt: String = "")

@import play.api.Play.resource
@import play.api.Play.current

@if(resource("public/" + path).isDefined) {
    <img src="@routes.Assets.at(path)" width="@width" height="@height" alt="@alt"/>
}
```

And use it this way:

```
<hr>
@img("images/favicon.png", 16, 16, "play framework logo")
<hr>
@img("images/not-existing.png", 16, 16, "foo bar")
<hr>
```

So it will result to:

```
<hr>
<img src="/assets/images/favicon.png" width="16" height="16" alt="play framework logo"/>
<hr>
<hr>
```

Project: https://github.com/schleichardt/stackoverflow-answers/tree/so18605473

Comment: I was using <img src="@routes.Assets.at("images/"+business.name+".png")" width="100" height="70" />. if(resource("public/" + path).isDefined)  is what i was looking for. Thank you for clear response!.